# Remove and replace build files of a particular entry in wepack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a webpack file that have multiple entry points, and it build each output of the entry files into a single build file.

for eg :

```
  commonSettings = {
    entry: {
      dashboard: "/manage/dashboard.js",
      settings: "/manage/settings.js",
     },
  }
```

So the issue is that each time i take build a particular entry, i will get more and more built files inside it.

```
dashboard-f1aw545234ej235213513.min.js
dashboard-f3ari2j3jn5b534k6j3rm.min.js
dashboard-f5kljh3q4jbkl2jrjkenn1.min.js
```

How can i replace the existing build file for the particular entry when am doing a new build ?

Comment: why don't you clean the output directory before webpack build starts?

Comment: I don't want to clean up the build file entirely, because there are other entry's build files as well, i just need to replace the build file of the particular file am building.

Comment: Then you should avoid using a hash in the name. If the build generates a n asset with a name which is same all the time, then these assets will replace the existing ones, otherwise they will keep adding to the output directory.

Comment: That could result in caching problems! @NalinRanjan

Comment: Well, of course... But you asked  to `replace`, and how will that happen if the generated asset has a unique name each time? By the way, what kind of `hash` is that, content hash??

Comment: If cleaning the output directory is a problem, then you could also try to delete only those files that are going to be built by the entry point, like for example, delete all `dashboard-*.js` files from output directory before you start building `dashboard` entry point.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be a good way, let me try it out. Thanks :) @NalinRanjan